# Top 20% Spender's Retention Rate

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

So, to start, this is finding our top 20% of highest spenders in 2010:

```
select top (20)percent o.BillEmail,SUM(o.total) as TotalSpent,
    count(o.OrderID) as TotalOrders
from dbo.tblOrder o with (nolock)
where o.DomainProjectID=13
    and o.BillEmail not like ''
    and o.OrderDate >= '2010-01-01'
    and o.OrderDate < '2011-01-01'
group by o.BillEmail
order by TotalSpent desc
```

From this, I need to find the retention rate of those top 20% spenders over the next two years.

Meaning, **which of the top 20% in 2010 stuck around and are on top in 2011, and then in 2012 as well?** Note: I'd need a count of how many were in 2010, then in 2011, then also in 2012.

I know it'd be much easier if I could create another table or pull from an excel sheet with only the top buyers listed. However, I don't have write access to our database so I have to do it all in nested queries, or whatever y'all have to suggest. I'm still a beginner so I don't know the best methods.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an interesting question.  Fundamentally, it is about migration in spending quintiles from one year to the next.  I would solve this by looking at all quintiles for the three years, to see where people move.

This starts with a summary of the data by year and email.  The key function is `ntile()`.  To be honest, I often do the calculation myself using `row_number()` and `count()`, which is why those are in the CTE (but not used subsequently):

```
with YearSummary as (
      select year(OrderDate) as yr, o.BillEmail, SUM(o.total) as TotalSpent,
             count(o.OrderID) as TotalOrders,
             row_number() over (partition by year(OrderDate) order by sum(o.Total) desc) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by year(OrderDate)) as NumInYear,
             ntile(5) over (partition by year(OrderDate) order by sum(o.Total) desc) as Quintile
      from dbo.tblOrder o with (nolock)
      where o.DomainProjectID=13 and o.BillEmail not like ''
      group by o.BillEmail, year(OrderDate)
     )
select q2010, q2011, q2012,
       count(*) as NumEmails,
       min(BillEmail), max(BillEmail)
from (select BillEmail,
             max(case when yr = 2010 then Quintile end) as q2010,
             max(case when yr = 2011 then Quintile end) as q2011,
             max(case when yr = 2012 then Quintile end) as q2012
      from YearSummary
      group by BillEmail
     ) ys
group by q2010, q2011, q2012
order by 1, 2, 3;
```

The final step is to take the multiple rows for each email and to combine them into counts.  Do note that some emails will not have any spending in certain years, so their corresponding `Quintile` will be NULL (this should actually produce more like 180 row - 5*6*6 - rather than 125 rows - 5*5*5

I also include sample emails in the final results (the `min()`and `max()`), which allow you to see samples for each group.

Note:  For the retention rate, calculate the ratio between (1, 1, 1) -- top tile in all years -- and the total in the top quintile in 2010.

Comment: Why use `PARTITION BY` `YEAR()` when already grouping by `YEAR()` in your cte?

Comment: @GoatCO . . . If I don't do `partition by year()` it will add up the numbers over all years in the data.  The use of window functions with aggregations produces awkward syntax.  I recommend that you rewrite that to use a subquery (do the aggregations first in the inner query, and the window function in the outer query).  That will help you see what is happening.

Comment: Actually it makes sense because of the email being in the group by too, it would be the count per email per year, instead of count per year.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;WITH top_2010 AS 
(
    select top (20)percent o.BillEmail,SUM(o.total) as TotalSpent,
        count(o.OrderID) as TotalOrders
    from dbo.tblOrder o with (nolock)
    where o.DomainProjectID=13
        and o.BillEmail not like ''
        and o.OrderDate >= '2010-01-01'
        and o.OrderDate < '2011-01-01'
    group by o.BillEmail
), 
top_2011 AS 
(
    select top (20)percent o.BillEmail,SUM(o.total) as TotalSpent,
        count(o.OrderID) as TotalOrders
    from dbo.tblOrder o with (nolock)
    where o.DomainProjectID=13
        and o.BillEmail not like ''
        and o.OrderDate >= '2011-01-01'
        and o.OrderDate < '2012-01-01'
    group by o.BillEmail
), 
top_2012 AS 
(
    select top (20)percent o.BillEmail,SUM(o.total) as TotalSpent,
        count(o.OrderID) as TotalOrders
    from dbo.tblOrder o with (nolock)
    where o.DomainProjectID=13
        and o.BillEmail not like ''
        and o.OrderDate >= '2012-01-01'
        and o.OrderDate < '2013-01-01'
    group by o.BillEmail
)
SELECT top_2010.*, 
    ISNULL(top_2011.TotalSpent, 0) AS [TotalSpent_2011],ISNULL(top_2011.TotalOrders, 0) AS [TotalOrders_2011] ,
    ISNULL(top_2012.TotalSpent, 0) AS [TotalSpent_2012],ISNULL(top_2012.TotalOrders, 0) AS [TotalOrders_2012]
FROM top_2010
LEFT JOIN top_2011 ON top_2010.BillEmail = top_2011.BillEmail 
LEFT JOIN top_2012 ON top_2010.BillEmail = top_2012.BillEmail 
WHERE top_2011.BillEmail IS NOT NULL OR top_2012.BillEmail IS NOT NULL
order by top_2010.TotalSpent desc
```

please note that I'm using `LEFT JOIN` so you can see all those that were in the top 2011 **or** 2012

if you need those that were in 2011 **AND** 2012 you can change to `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [common table expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to accomplish this. Create a top 20% listing for each year, and then inner join them to find which companies are in the top quintile for all three years. Because you want only records which are present in all three years, you should not use left joins.

```
WITH Top2010 AS (
select top (20)percent o.BillEmail,SUM(o.total) as TotalSpent,
    count(o.OrderID) as TotalOrders
from dbo.tblOrder o with (nolock)
where o.DomainProjectID=13
    and o.BillEmail not like ''
    and o.OrderDate >= '2010-01-01'
    and o.OrderDate < '2011-01-01'
group by o.BillEmail
order by TotalSpent desc
),
Top2011 AS (
select top (20)percent o.BillEmail,SUM(o.total) as TotalSpent,
    count(o.OrderID) as TotalOrders
from dbo.tblOrder o with (nolock)
where o.DomainProjectID=13
    and o.BillEmail not like ''
    and o.OrderDate >= '2011-01-01'
    and o.OrderDate < '2012-01-01'
group by o.BillEmail
order by TotalSpent desc
),
Top2012 AS (
select top (20)percent o.BillEmail,SUM(o.total) as TotalSpent,
    count(o.OrderID) as TotalOrders
from dbo.tblOrder o with (nolock)
where o.DomainProjectID=13
    and o.BillEmail not like ''
    and o.OrderDate >= '2012-01-01'
    and o.OrderDate < '2013-01-01'
group by o.BillEmail
order by TotalSpent desc
)

SELECT Top2010.BillEmail -- plus whatever other columns you want
FROM Top2010
INNER JOIN Top2011 ON Top2010.BillEmail = Top2011.BillEmail
INNER JOIN Top2012 ON Top2012.BillEmail = Top2011.BillEmail
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd use a couple of CTEs; one per year. I'd also name things a little more generically (rather than embedding the year name everywhere). Once we've got our resultsets we can use `EXISTS` to check who was around in all 3 periods.

```
-- Get the 1st Jan in the  current year
DECLARE @current_year date = DateAdd(yy, DateDiff(yy, 0, Current_Timestamp), 0);

; WITH highest_spenders_2_years_ago AS (
  <your_query>
  WHERE  o.orderDate >= DateAdd(yy, -2, @current_year)
  AND    o.orderDate <  DateAdd(yy, -1, @current_year)
)
, highest_spenders_last_year AS (
  <your_query>
  WHERE  o.orderDate >= DateAdd(yy, -1, @current_year)
  AND    o.orderDate <  DateAdd(yy,  0, @current_year)
)
, highest_spenders_this_year AS (
  <your_query>
  WHERE  o.orderDate >= DateAdd(yy,  0, @current_year)
  AND    o.orderDate <  DateAdd(yy,  1, @current_year)
)
SELECT *
FROM   highest_spenders_this_year
WHERE  EXISTS (
         SELECT *
         FROM   highest_spenders_last_year
         WHERE  BillEmail = highest_spenders_this_year.BillEmail
       )
AND    EXISTS (
         SELECT *
         FROM   highest_spenders_2_years_ago
         WHERE  BillEmail = highest_spenders_this_year.BillEmail
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Base2010.BillEmail, 
CASE WHEN retention2011.BillEmail = '' THEN 'Not retained' ELSE 'Retained' END AS retained2011, 
CASE WHEN retention2012.BillEmail = '' THEN 'Not retained' ELSE 'Retained' END AS retained2012
FROM 
    (select top (20)percent o.BillEmail,SUM(o.total) as TotalSpent,
        count(o.OrderID) as TotalOrders, BillEmail
    from dbo.tblOrder o with (nolock)
    where o.DomainProjectID=13
        and o.BillEmail not like ''
        and o.OrderDate >= '2010-01-01'
        and o.OrderDate < '2011-01-01'
    group by o.BillEmail
    ) AS Base2010

LEFT JOIN
    (select top (20)percent o.BillEmail,SUM(o.total) as TotalSpent,
        count(o.OrderID) as TotalOrders, BillEmail 
    from dbo.tblOrder o with (nolock)
    where o.DomainProjectID=13
        and o.BillEmail not like ''
        and o.OrderDate >= '2011-01-01'
        and o.OrderDate < '2012-01-01'
    group by o.BillEmail
    ) AS retention2011
ON Base2010.BillEmail = retention2011.BillEmail

LEFT JOIN
    (select top (20)percent o.BillEmail,SUM(o.total) as TotalSpent,
        count(o.OrderID) as TotalOrders, BillEmail
    from dbo.tblOrder o with (nolock)
    where o.DomainProjectID=13
        and o.BillEmail not like ''
        and o.OrderDate >= '2012-01-01'
        and o.OrderDate < '2013-01-01'
    group by o.BillEmail
    ) AS retention2012
ON Base2010.BillEmail = retention2012.BillEmail
```